# Reload a page once in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to reload a page in angular once when a user visits it but this fails

This is what ive tried

In the homepage component i have

```
export class HomepageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    location.reload();
  }

}
```

The page keeps on refreshing without stopping how can i reload only once on init

Comment: I'm wondering, why do you need to reload the page when they come to the component?

Comment: If you need to do a reload only once you would need to pass something into the component that could say if it has been reloaded, my guess would be to use a route param or read something from the query string? So instead of a straight .reload(), you would use a route to navigate back to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will check the query in the url the first time the page gets loaded and will reload right after. This will happen only once (the first time page loads).

```
ngOnInit(){
      let win = (window as any);
      if(win.location.search !== '?loaded' ) {
          win.location.search = '?loaded';
          win.location.reload();
      }
  }
```

Comment: The reload never happens, am using has in my routing so a typical route looks like: http://localhost:4200/#/home

Comment: Try my updated answer. You can adjust it per page if necessary.

Comment: now this also keeps on reloading and adding the #/home?loaded to the url

Comment: Ok, this happened because you were using hash in your url routing. Try my updated answer. It should be fine now.

Comment: Still continuusly reloading for me

Answer (score 2):

I got a simple solution as follows

```
ngOnInit() {
  if (!localStorage.getItem('foo')) { 
    localStorage.setItem('foo', 'no reload') 
    location.reload() 
  } else {
    localStorage.removeItem('foo') 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On Angular 5, I capture the loaded query string param and if exists, stop reloading

 because Amcharts is not displaying on first load and only displays on reload

```
ngOnInit() {
    var urlParams = [];
    window.location.search.replace("?", "").split("&").forEach(function (e, i) {
        var p = e.split("=");
        urlParams[p[0]] = p[1];
    });

    // We have all the params now -> you can access it by name
    console.log(urlParams["loaded"]);

    if(urlParams["loaded"]) {}else{

        let win = (window as any);
        win.location.search = '?loaded=1';
        //win.location.reload('?loaded=1');
    }

}
```