# The css transitions in angular 5 do not work

Tags: css, angular, angular-animations

I have some css transitions, but these do not work when I go from one page to another, they only work when I reload the page, I leave some sample images. Someone could help me ?

**It should be noted that the transitions are in CSS files.**

[image: **When I pass between pages.**]

[image: **When I reload the page.**]

```css
.login-page .login-form {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 60px;
  -moz-transition: all 550ms ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 550ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 550ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 550ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-form">
  <div class="login-content">
    <form method="post" role="form" action="#" autocomplete="off">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="entypo-user"></i>
          </div>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="entypo-mail"></i>
          </div>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Correo electronico"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="entypo-lock"></i>
          </div>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="entypo-lock"></i>
          </div>
          <input type="password" name="repear-password" id="repeat-password" class="form-control" placeholder="Repita su contraseña"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why won't you provide any code?

Comment: Think about it. How are we supposed to help you if you don't give us the problematic code? We're not just going to recode the whole thing for you.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake, and put the code, thank you very much.

Comment: as per your tags, it seems like you're using angular framework, and I'm supposing that you're using angular routing concept, you can use [angular animation](https://angular.io/guide/animations) for transitions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your css is not replicating to the next page.
    So when you are routing to next page, please call function windows.reload() [**Not recalling exact function name]. This will solve the transition problem.
    For reference please check this .
    [Reload Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42684565/reload-a-page-once-in-angular2)

Comment: seems like you're talking about [window.location.reload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)

Comment: It becomes recursive

Comment: to which function you have wrote that code. if it is in Init it gets called only once in lifecycle or if in constructor it gets called as many times as the component initialized. If possible please share the code