# How to reload a page once using angular or javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to reload a page after routing to a new component

I have tried location.reload() option but it keeps on reloading without stoping

```
ngOninit(){
location.reload()
}
```

Expected result :

I need to reload a page only oncee

Actual result :

It is reloading many times

Comment: Can you show more code? Like where you're calling ngOninit()

Comment: ngOnInit is called when the component is loaded

Comment: @Sudhin, can you describe your use case ? Why did you need to reload only one time ?

Comment: When do you want to trigger the reload? If it's oninit, it's going to run that code every time the page is reloaded

Comment: No i am not calling any api or anything , i need to reload a component as soons as it got  loaded

Comment: as per ur code its keeps on getting reloaded.
whats your use case?

Comment: I need to reload a page as soon as the component is loaded completey to refresh a page

Comment: But if you reload, the component is loaded and if your component is loaded you want to reload, this is a creation of infinite loop

Comment: window.location.reload() using javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reload a page once in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42684565/reload-a-page-once-in-angular2)

Comment: use <img [src]="{{awsUrl}}" alt="Random first slide"> , Notice the square bracket around source

Comment: @Sudhin I rolled back your question to original. You cannot change the question to another question while it has answers. The answers would be irrelevant to the question then.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't understand your use case but there is lot of way to make what you want.

I propose you a way with localStorage.

Check if a localStorage exist. By default the key don't exist, so you create it and reload the page too.
After the refresh you check the same key (that exist now). So you don't reload the page and remove the key for the next time

```js
ngOnInit() {
  if (!localStorage.getItem('foo')) { 
    localStorage.setItem('foo', 'no reload') 
    location.reload() 
  } else {
    localStorage.removeItem('foo') 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should save (for example) "IsLoadedBefore" boolean in a variable and check it before reloading your page. but a variable that keeps data after page reloaded! (not local ones)

`localStorage` is a good choice:

```
function reloadIfNecessary() {
var isLoadedBefore = localstorage.getItem("IsLoadedBefore");
if(isLoadedBefore=="true")
   return;
}
else {
localstorage.setItem("IsLoadedBefore",true);
/*use your reload method*/
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reload child component use this.ngOnInit(); (on child component which may be refreshed) to reload just this child component.

parent.component.ts

```
@ViewChild(ChildComponent) child: ChildComponent;
refreshed = false;
ngAfterViewInit() {
  if (!refreshed)
     this.child.refresh()
  refreshed = true;
}
```

child.component.ts

```
refresh() {
   this.ngOnInit()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can import location

```
constructor(location: Location)
```

then call reload method to reload the page

```
this.location.reload()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a service to store the previous route. Get the previous route in your component if it has route or the route you define in condition, then reload.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class PreviousRouteService {

  private prev: string;
  private curr: string;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.currentUrl = this.router.url;
    router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {        
        this.prev = this.curr;
        this.curr = event.url;
      };
    });
  }

  public getPreviousUrl() {
    return this.prev;
  }    
}
```

Use it in your component:

```
ngOninit(){
  if (this.previousRouteService.getPreviousUrl() {
    location.reload()
  }
}
```

Use the service as provider and instantiate it in the constructor.

```
constructor(private previousRouteService: PreviousRouteService){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can make use of local-storage like below

```
ngOnInit(){
 const firstTime = localstorage.getItem('key')
 if(!firstTime){
  localstorage.setItem('key','loaded')
  location.reload()
 }else {
   localStorage.removeItem('key') 
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In javascript, you can use

location.reload()

for page reload